# How to call a web service (.asmx ) or a wcf service (.svc) via ssis package?

Tags: wcf, web-services, ssis, scheduling

Is it possible calling a service (web service or wcf service) via a ssis package in order to schedule running it as a job?

Thank you for any sugestions

Comment: The running package is going to call a web service in order to schedule the package to run?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can invoke a web service from an SSIS package.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/webservicessis.aspx

Whether or not that's a good design decision is another question:

- Does it couple the tiers too tightly?
- Is it secure? (probably, if you are only making outgoing calls, or calling an internal service)