# How can i create a webservice which is checking table for some periodically in database in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to checking my database table for periodically.So how can i create a webservice and how can i configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically what you need is, something which is always running and hence can make periodic calls.

There are a number of ways to do it

1. (Since ASP.NET hence) You can make a Windows Service, and host this service on your server, since server is always running, this Windows Service will make request to your webservice, update database or watever you want
2. You can use SQL Jobs to do it. You can call a webservice from a job, through a SSIS (Sql Server Integration Service) Package. These packages are very very robust in nature, they can do almost any db activity that you want them to do, including webservice request.
3. And finally, you can use third party tools such as Quartz.Net

## References:

1. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470445/how-to-call-webservice-from-windows-service) is how you can call a webservice through a windows service.
2. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691964/how-to-call-a-web-service-asmx-or-a-wcf-service-svc-via-ssis-package) is how you can call a webservice through a ssis package.
3. [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/23/sql-server-running-ssis-package-in-scheduled-job/) is how you can integrate a SSIS package in a SQL Job
4. [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample) is how you can create a windows service
5. [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/218914/Steps-to-Create-your-First-SSIS-Package) is how you can create a SSIS package
6. [this](http://www.google.com) is how you can get answer/tutorial of almost anything

## Example:

simplest of all of these would be a Windows Service. Making a windows service and hosting it on the machine(server) is very easy, use one of the given links (specially the last link). Usually, in Windows Service, you do some activity in `OnStart` event. you can place a timer inside this `OnStart` and upon `TimerTick()`, you can request your webservice.

something like this:

```
class Program : ServiceBase
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new Program());
        }
        public Program()
        {
            this.ServiceName = "My Service";
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
            InitializeTimer();

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();

            //TODO: clean up any variables and stop any threads
        }

        protected void InitializeTimer()
        {
            try
            {
                if (timer == null)
                {
                    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    timer.Enabled = true;
                    timer.AutoReset = true;
                    timer.Interval = 60000 * 1;
                    timer.Enabled = true;
                    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utility.WriteLog("Exception InitialiseTimer : " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }

        protected void timer_Elapsed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
                        
            TimerTick();
            timer.Interval = 60000 * Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimerInerval"]);
        }

        private void TimerTick()
        {
            try
            {
                DownloadFromFTPandValidate objDownLoadandValidate = new DownloadFromFTPandValidate();
                objDownLoadandValidate.ProcessMain();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utility.WriteLog("Exception InitialiseTimer : " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, class `DownloadFromFTPandValidate` wraps the code to db activity. It shd give you an idea.

Comment: i want to checked just if particular user is registerd or not but this thing is should checking for some period of time.. This thing how should i do?

Comment: since they are always running, and they have to always run in order for a periodic execution. always running doesn't mean always executing. you can always configure your service to execute a particular set of code after fixed interval, same goes for jobs

Comment: ssis packages are meant to do this. to run at a certain interval i.e. every night at 11pm or on a certain period i.e. after every 2hours. In one of my projects, I've 15+ SSIS packages, doing all shitfull works i.e. google api, weather service, db update, email parsing and wat not

Comment: I also want to run or call a one method which checking a every day 1 time for user already exist or not..

Comment: watever sejal. any plain activity that you can do manually(through a button click) through asp.net, you can do from them. see the example i've posted, its c#. you can write ur logic to check user exists or not. go on, dig more abt them

Comment: Thanks for such a kind help.

Comment: how can i run this windows service? can u tell me?

Comment: goto Visual Studio, click on New, and choose windows on the left and then, look for Windows Service template in the right window. choose tht. its simple to configure it. you can deploy a windows service, in a most simple way, by using a setup project. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.100).aspx  and   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317421 .

Comment: u mean i have to create a exe? i can not directly run like as a website one of page we run simply?

Comment: :).yes. tht's the whole point of creating windows service or ssis. you want it to get scheduled. you cannot do it through a website. code has to be at some location, where it can be scheduled, one such location is windows service. we are again at the beginning of this entire discussion.

Comment: yes becoz i cn not understand how to do this so.. i asking u a lots of que.. :(

Comment: now i create a one webservice in which one method and i called that method into window service.. now i want to check that its working or not.. i directly run but its not run and give me error

Comment: this is a new prlbm altogether. try finding tutorials or questions on running web services inside a windows service. you should begin with the fact "It is possible", and let's close this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a job scheduler for periodical task. I recommend you a good one. Check out this link: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a trigger on your table which runs a stored procedure once data was modified, then use the [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to access the commandline form your stored procedure so you can run for example a batch file or whatever.